# Can't combine HTTPClient with RxJS subject in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to create a service that will hold the data received from REST API than emits it to whom ever needs it. 
I used BehaviorSubject and managed to get the data in the template (using *ngFor) but whatever I tried, I can't get it in a component. The flow is that a some component calls fetchCustomersDetails than renders the data as a list. 
Once the user clicks a customer, the name passed to another page where I wish to filter the data in the service and retrieve the match. 
Examine the code shows that the name of the customer (from the list fetched in the service) is passed to getCustomerByCompanyName but the subject contain an empty array where the data needs to be saved. 
I'm very new to Angular and it seems I'm missing some concept of using observables. 
Thank you for your help. 
Here is what I tried so far:

```js
    /* Service */
    export class CustomerDetailsService {
      private apiUrl: string = `https://...`;
      private readonly customersDetailsPool$: BehaviorSubject<ICustomerDetails[]> = new BehaviorSubject<ICustomerDetails[]>([]);
    
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    
      fetchCustomersDetails(){
        return this.http.get<ICustomerDetails[]>(this.apiUrl)
          .subscribe({
            next: ((customerDetailsList: ICustomerDetails[]) => this.customersDetailsPool$.next(customerDetailsList)),
            error: ((error: any) => this.handleError(error)),
            complete: (() => console.log("test: ", this.customersDetailsPool$))
          })
      }
    
      get customersDetailsPool(): Observable<ICustomerDetails[]> {
        return this.customersDetailsPool$.asObservable();
      }
    
      getCustomerByCompanyName(name: string) {
        console.log("customersDetailsPool: ", this.customersDetailsPool$);
        return this.customersDetailsPool$.pipe(
          map((customers: ICustomerDetails[]) => {customers.find((customer) => {customer.company === name})})
        )
      }
    }
```

```js
    /* component */
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-customer-edit-page',
      templateUrl: './customer-edit-page.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./customer-edit-page.component.scss'],
      providers: [CustomerDetailsService]
    })
    
    export class CustomerEditPageComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
      @ViewChild(CustomerDetailsComponent)
      private customerNewDetails!: CustomerDetailsComponent;
      customerName: string | null = '';
      isEdit: boolean = false;
      customerDetails: ICustomerDetails = {
        company: '',
        contacts: [],
      };
      
      constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        public customerDetailsService: CustomerDetailsService,
      ) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.customerName = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('company');
        this.isEdit = this.isToEdit();
        if (this.customerName) {
          this.customerDetailsService.getCustomerByCompanyName(this.customerName)
          .subscribe((customer) => {
            if (customer) {
              this.customerDetails = customer;
            }
          })
          .unsubscribe();
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: When do you use FetchCustomerDetails()? Because that's needed for getting the actual details in your beehaviourSubject

Comment: @CharlieV I use FetchCustomerDetails() in a different component and I can see the data in both the related page and the console.log found in the complete method of subscribe.

Answer (score 3):

You've got a syntax error in your `find` call.

```js
customers.find((customer) => {customer.company === name})
```

This does not return anything, Either add `return` or remove the curly braces.

```js
customers.find((customer) => {return customer.company === name})
```

OR

```js
customers.find((customer) => customer.company === name)
```

Without braces, `return` is implicit.

The way you have it set up, you also need to call `fetchCustomerDetails()` at some point, and you can't just unsubscribe immediately, because you have no idea if the initial http request from `fetchCustomerDetails()` has completed yet, unless you have a mechanism in place that you haven't showed.

---

I just noticed you have the same error in the surrounding map call. Remove the braces or add return there as well.

```js
      map((customers: ICustomerDetails[]) =>
        customers.find((customer) => customer.company === name)
      )
```

---

Here's a working simulation if you still have any discrepancies.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-17tsrm?file=src/app/customer-details.service.ts

Comment: The changes didn't had any effect. I am calling the fetchCustomerDetails in a previous component (list which works well) and was hoping it will store the data indefinitely in customersDetailsPool$ so that I can find a specific customer than edit it. As I already fetched all the data I need, my problem is creating the store for other components. How can I achieve that? I am completely lost  with all the pipes and subscriptions.

Comment: You have the same error in the surrounding map call, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're immediately unsubscribing from the service observable, which is probably creating some async timing issue

Remove the `unsubscribe()`, and instead use a `takeUntil` - you can lookup examples of `takeUntil` with `ngOnDestroy`

Comment: I put the unsubscribe in a comment, unfortunately, nothing changed. Other ideas would be much appreciated.